# Ajax using jQuery and CodeIgniter, ajax call doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a contact form in CodeIgniter, using jQuery and ajax to load a message when the submit button has been pressed. I've done the tutorial [*CodeIgniter from Scratch: Day 8 – AJAX*](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-8-ajax/) from net.tutsplus.com, but I can't get it working. By pressing the submit button the text "thank you" should appear instead of the contact form, this is a separate php file (I'm going to make it just a text line on the same page when I've figured out how to do that). If I press the submit button nothing happens but if I write an alert inside the `$.ajax({})` or if I remove the comma after `data: form_data` the view is changed to the "thank you" view but the "have you typed your name"-check is not performed. I'm new to Ajax and have no idea why it isn't working and I would be very happy if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and explain why the view change works but not the name check if I add an alert or remove the comma. (of course these actions give error messages in the Chrome console since it's not supposed to be like that)
I'm using a template to include header, footer and main_content.

In short: Why doesn't the following ajax call work?

controller:

```
    <?php
    class Contact extends CI_Controller{
        function index(){

        $data['main_content']='contact_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

    function submit(){

        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $is_ajax=$this->input->post('ajax');
        $data['main_content']='contact_form_thanks';

        if($is_ajax){
            $this->load->view($data['main_content']);
        }else{
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
<div id="contact_form">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
        <?php
            echo form_open('contact/submit');
            echo form_input('name','Name', 'id="name"');
            echo form_input('email', 'Email', 'id="email"');
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'message', 
                'cols' => 30, 
                'rows' => 12
            );
            echo form_textarea($data, 'Message', 'id="message"');
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Send message', 'id="submit"');
            echo form_close();
        ?>
</div><!--end contact-form-->
<!--Dissable the submit function-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if(!name || name == 'Name'){
        alert('Please enter your name');
        return false;
    }

    var form_data = {
        //csrf_token: $('input[name*="csrf_token"]').val(),
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        message: $('#message').val(),
        ajax: '1'
    };
    //array
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('contact/submit'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#main_content').html(msg);
        }
        //alert('bye'); //Why does it "work" when I write alert?


    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="sv-se" lang="sv-se">
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
```

Comment: And what does your sniffer say? I mean something like developers panel in Chrome, "network" tab where all server requests are logged. Here we could see your real ajax request and raw server response.

Comment: OT from directly answering your question, but this would be worth a read for you, I think: http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/04/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-framework-x

Comment: Thanks! the link was helpful. There are so much to learn!

Answer (score -1):

Add an error callback !

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('contact/submit'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(msg){
        $('#main_content').html(msg);
    },
    error: function (XHR, status, response) {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

And precise the dataType

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('contact/submit'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: form_data
}).done(function (msg, status, XHR) {
    // Manage the server response here !
    $('#main_content').html(msg);
}).fail(function (XHR, status, response) {
    // an error has occured, probably the CSRF protection.
    // console.log(XHR, status, response); to get more informations.
    // the "network" tab of the Google Chrome console should helps you too, as zeliboba suggested !
});
```

Comment: You're mixing `$.ajax` parameters and jXHR chaining. These are different things. `jXHR.success()` is deprecated, `$.ajax({ success: ... })` – is not.

Comment: Ahmmm maybe yeah, didn't see the doc like that ! Thanks !
But anyway, an error callback should always be catched in any ajax request.

Comment: feel free to fix inappropriate tense.